# How to pass a variable from template to a view

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

My page has two models into it. They all inherit from one base model: Entry.

```
class Entry(models.Model):
    author_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    author_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    author = GenericForeignKey("author_type", "author_id")

    text = models.TextField()

    class Meta:
        abstract=True
        ordering = ["date_created", "date_updated"]


class Post(Entry):
    comments = GenericRelation(Comment, related_query_name="post")

    def __str__(self):
        return f"POST(ID{self.id})"


class Discussion(Entry):
    head = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    comments = GenericRelation(Comment, related_query_name="discussion")
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f"DISCUSSION(ID{self.id})"
```

Template:

```
{% block main %}
    {% for entry in entries %}
        <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
            <img src="{{entry.image}}" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
            <div class="card-body">
                {% if entry.head %}
                    <h5 class="card-title">{{ entry.head }}</h5>
                {% else %}
                    <p class="card-text">{{entry.text|slice:"0:20"}}</p>
                {% endif %}
                <a href="{% url 'posts:comments' entry.id %}" class="btn btn-primary">Comments</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

How can I pass a variable that will distinguish them in a corresponding view, or are there any better ways of doing it?

```
<a href="{% url 'posts:comments' entry.id %}" class="btn btn-primary">Comments</a>
```

My guess is that I need to pass a variable in a URL tag, that will be passed in a view, but I don't know how to do it. Is it the way? Or can I implement it in some better way?

Comment: can you share views.py too.

Comment: Also, you can use Ajax

Comment: @SaeedRamezani, can you explain it?